# Getting all of the ungrouped parts of a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to separate a string into two variables and the way to indicate this in the regex pattern is that the things that I want to go to the first variables are the grouped things (they are surrounded by parenthesis) and the things that go to the second are not.

I can take the things of the first variable by exploiting the group() method but I do not know how I can take the parts without parenthesis

```py
import re
number_of_needed_groups = 2
string_example = "my name is (Nimrod) and my last name is (Rappaport)"
pattern = r'my name is (.+) and my last name is (.+)'
var1 = None
for i in range(1,number_of_needed_groups + 1):
    var1 += re.match(pattern,string_example).group(i)

var2 = ???
```

I do not actually know what string_example will be so i cant make that without using some kind of pattern recognition

I think that var 1 should work and I would like to find a way to make var2 be equal "my name is and my last name is" (this is not my actual data)

Comment: you dont have to have the for loop for `var1`, take a look at [the groups function](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.match.groups)

Comment: Your example is overconfusing. Does it mean the pattern always matches the input string? If not add something to the sample text. Also, provide exact expected results. Why not a list of values? Are you sure you need them as strings?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it bothers you that there are parentheses in the match strings, then edit the regular expression to:

`my name is \((. +)\) And my last name is \((. +)\)`

`()` is expression for Match group.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much you want the actual solution to look like your provided code since it is a little bit vague what the use is. But trying to keep it as close to the original as possible, you could try something like this:

```
import re

number_of_needed_groups = 2

string_example = "my name is (Nimrod) and my last name is (Rappaport)"
pattern = r'my name is (.+) and my last name is (.+)'

#Combine all the matches together as one string
reg_match = re.match(pattern, string_example)
var1 = "".join(reg_match.groups())
var2 = string_example

#Loop though the matches and remove them from the string one at a time.
for key, match in enumerate(re.findall(pattern, string_example)[0]):
    var2 = var2.replace(match, '')

print (var1)
print (var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.finall` to grab all the output within parenthesis and use `re.sub` to get a new string without substrings in parenthesis

```
>>> var1 = ' '.join (re.findall(r'\(.*?\)', string_example))
>>> var2 = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', string_example)           
>>>
>>> print (var1)
(Nimrod) (Rappaport)
>>> print (var2)
my name is  and my last name is
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will

- Find all matches
- Put all captures into `caps` list
- Put all non-captured parts into a `non-caps` list.

**Note** it does not handle:

- Groups inside optional groups
- Nested capturing groups

Python code:

```
import re
string_example = "my name is (Nimrod) and my last name is (Rappaport)"
pattern = r'my name is (.+) and my last name is (.+)'
regx = re.compile(pattern)
caps = []
uncaps = []
for m in regx.finditer(string_example):
    n_caps = []
    n_uncaps = []
    start_from = 0
    for group_id in range(regx.groups):
        n_caps.append(m.group(group_id+1))
        n_uncaps.append(m.group()[start_from:m.start(group_id+1)-m.start()])
        start_from = m.end(group_id+1)-m.start()
    if start_from < len(m.group()):
        n_uncaps.append(m.group()[start_from:])
    caps.append(n_caps)
    uncaps.append(n_uncaps)

print(caps)
print(uncaps)
```

Result:

```
[['(Nimrod)', '(Rappaport)']]
[['my name is ', ' and my last name is ']]
```

See [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1lyvI7)